# App that runs locally and builds and deploys on Heroku but shows an application error when I try to open it

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, heroku

I am building a MERN stack app. My Node server runs locally and connects to the MongoDB Database. It also builds and deploys on Heroku. But when I click Open App on the Heroku page, it says "Application Error."

I have tried changing the port from a static port to process.env.PORT in my server file. I still receive the application error. I have checked the Heroku logs but I'm not sure which part is causing the issue or how to fix it.

These are the Heroku logs:

```
Mikes-MacBook-Pro-2:MealAppeal mikemooney$ heroku logs --tail
2019-04-28T19:06:49.254157+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
2019-04-28T19:06:49.258286+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] cd backend && node server.js exited with code 1
2019-04-28T19:06:49.523188+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]
2019-04-28T19:06:49.523200+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] > reactpractice@0.1.0 start /app/client
2019-04-28T19:06:49.523203+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] > react-scripts start
2019-04-28T19:06:49.523205+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]
2019-04-28T19:06:49.527698+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
2019-04-28T19:06:49.531427+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! file sh
2019-04-28T19:06:49.531429+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-04-28T19:06:49.531715+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2019-04-28T19:06:49.531717+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! syscall spawn
2019-04-28T19:06:49.532769+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! reactpractice@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
2019-04-28T19:06:49.532771+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2019-04-28T19:06:49.532772+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR!
2019-04-28T19:06:49.536200+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the reactpractice@0.1.0 start script.
2019-04-28T19:06:49.536203+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-04-28T19:06:49.595881+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
2019-04-28T19:06:49.596389+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]
2019-04-28T19:06:49.596733+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-04-28T19:06:49.596736+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-04-28T19_06_49_533Z-debug.log
2019-04-28T19:06:49.601383+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] cd client && npm start exited with code 1
2019-04-28T19:06:49.610970+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-04-28T19:06:49.611416+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-04-28T19:06:49.612556+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! MealAppeal@1.0.0 start: `concurrently "cd backend && node server.js" "cd client && npm start"`
2019-04-28T19:06:49.612719+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-04-28T19:06:49.612968+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-04-28T19:06:49.613142+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the MealAppeal@1.0.0 start script.
2019-04-28T19:06:49.613304+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-04-28T19:06:49.694297+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-04-28T19:06:49.694458+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-04-28T19:06:49.694583+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-04-28T19_06_49_614Z-debug.log
2019-04-28T19:06:49.762585+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-04-28T19:06:49.740377+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-04-28T19:06:49.982478+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-04-28T19:06:53.516443+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2019-04-28T19:06:56.184569+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-04-28T19:06:56.184587+00:00 app[web.1]: > MealAppeal@1.0.0 start /app
2019-04-28T19:06:56.184589+00:00 app[web.1]: > concurrently "cd backend && node server.js" "cd client && npm start"
2019-04-28T19:06:56.184591+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-04-28T19:06:56.940574+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:584
2019-04-28T19:06:56.940619+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]     throw err;
2019-04-28T19:06:56.940622+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]     ^
2019-04-28T19:06:56.940623+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]
2019-04-28T19:06:56.940625+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] Error: Cannot find module 'express'
2019-04-28T19:06:56.940628+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
2019-04-28T19:06:56.940630+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
2019-04-28T19:06:56.940632+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
2019-04-28T19:06:56.940634+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
2019-04-28T19:06:56.940636+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/backend/server.js:1:79)
2019-04-28T19:06:56.940637+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
2019-04-28T19:06:56.940639+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
2019-04-28T19:06:56.940641+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
2019-04-28T19:06:56.940642+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
2019-04-28T19:06:56.940644+00:00 app[web.1]: [0]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
2019-04-28T19:06:56.944428+00:00 app[web.1]: [0] cd backend && node server.js exited with code 1
2019-04-28T19:06:57.311873+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]
2019-04-28T19:06:57.311886+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] > reactpractice@0.1.0 start /app/client
2019-04-28T19:06:57.311888+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] > react-scripts start
2019-04-28T19:06:57.311890+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]
2019-04-28T19:06:57.322012+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] sh: 1: react-scripts: not found
2019-04-28T19:06:57.332830+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! file sh
2019-04-28T19:06:57.333782+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-04-28T19:06:57.334066+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! errno ENOENT
2019-04-28T19:06:57.334452+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! syscall spawn
2019-04-28T19:06:57.344495+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! reactpractice@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
2019-04-28T19:06:57.344500+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
2019-04-28T19:06:57.344503+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR!
2019-04-28T19:06:57.344504+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! Failed at the reactpractice@0.1.0 start script.
2019-04-28T19:06:57.344506+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-04-28T19:06:57.351532+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
2019-04-28T19:06:57.351535+00:00 app[web.1]: [1]
2019-04-28T19:06:57.351537+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-04-28T19:06:57.351539+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-04-28T19_06_57_343Z-debug.log
2019-04-28T19:06:57.364856+00:00 app[web.1]: [1] cd client && npm start exited with code 1
2019-04-28T19:06:57.377876+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2019-04-28T19:06:57.378703+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2019-04-28T19:06:57.380999+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! MealAppeal@1.0.0 start: `concurrently "cd backend && node server.js" "cd client && npm start"`
2019-04-28T19:06:57.381328+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2019-04-28T19:06:57.381816+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2019-04-28T19:06:57.382171+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the MealAppeal@1.0.0 start script.
2019-04-28T19:06:57.382478+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2019-04-28T19:06:57.390608+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2019-04-28T19:06:57.391002+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2019-04-28T19:06:57.391234+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2019-04-28T19_06_57_384Z-debug.log
2019-04-28T19:06:57.513345+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-04-28T19:06:57.493309+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-04-28T19:06:59.681145+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mealappeal.herokuapp.com request_id=7a653da1-edfd-4b92-b3ea-c49e10943b8f fwd="73.196.166.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-04-28T19:07:06.536235+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mealappeal.herokuapp.com request_id=c5518b49-ccd6-4066-b193-e717609a2cec fwd="73.196.166.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-04-28T19:08:21.969940+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mealappeal.herokuapp.com request_id=7e88ce38-894b-42ed-80bb-a43f51deec57 fwd="73.196.166.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-04-28T19:08:42.534226+00:00 app[api]: Starting process with command `reset` by user 
2019-04-28T19:08:45.263724+00:00 heroku[run.4224]: State changed from starting to up
2019-04-28T19:08:45.121272+00:00 heroku[run.4224]: Awaiting client
2019-04-28T19:08:45.142193+00:00 heroku[run.4224]: Starting process with command `reset`
2019-04-28T19:08:50.401585+00:00 heroku[run.4224]: State changed from up to complete
2019-04-28T19:08:50.384535+00:00 heroku[run.4224]: Process exited with status 0
2019-04-28T19:08:57.669820+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mealappeal.herokuapp.com request_id=d1c7bb40-f2b3-4132-a784-55b98ce3f75b fwd="73.196.166.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-04-28T19:18:36.447223+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mealappeal.herokuapp.com request_id=8fe67168-8085-4fb7-8d6a-65280e1b5f5f fwd="73.196.166.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-04-28T19:18:36.900372+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mealappeal.herokuapp.com request_id=20fc5556-c2c8-4938-9726-8096c704503c fwd="73.196.166.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-04-28T19:23:39.919432+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mealappeal.herokuapp.com request_id=3e1c874d-db0f-4001-a736-c398bb16f3a7 fwd="73.196.166.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2019-04-28T19:24:35.668319+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=mealappeal.herokuapp.com request_id=ddefce58-1014-429d-a585-1fe792609215 fwd="73.196.166.129" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

These are my package.json files:

```
Backend:
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "test": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "mongodb": "^3.2.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.5.2"
  }
}

Front:
{
  "name": "reactpractice",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "proxy": "http://localhost:3001/",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "mdreact": "^0.1.5",
    "mdbreact": "^4.13.0",
    "react": "^16.8.5",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.8",
    "react-select": "^2.4.3",
    "react-selectize": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}

Root:
{
  "name": "MealAppeal",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "express-session": "^1.16.1",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "passport-local-mongoose": "^5.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "concurrently \"cd backend && node server.js\" \"cd client && npm start\""
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/mmooney363/MealAppeal.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/mmooney363/MealAppeal/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/mmooney363/MealAppeal#readme"
}
```

Comment: Please post you `package.json` file

Comment: edit the question and put it there, including the one for your react/front-end?

Comment: OK, I've edited the question.

Comment: error says `sh: 1: react-scripts: not found`, did you `eject` or `build` your react app?

Answer (score 1):

When you push to Heroku it will run `npm install` in the root folder and then `npm start`.

In your root folder you have the following dependencies:

```
"concurrently": "^4.1.0",
"express-session": "^1.16.1",
"passport": "^0.4.0",
"passport-local": "^1.0.0",
"passport-local-mongoose": "^5.0.1"
```

It will install those, but not the ones in the backend or front folder. You have to make sure the packages in those folders gets installed too. You can use a "postinstall" script to do that. E.g.

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "concurrently \"cd backend && node server.js\" \"cd client && npm start\""
    "postinstall": "cd backend && npm install && cd ../client && npm install && npm run build","
  }
```

postinstall will run after `npm install` has run.

You should also not run `react-scripts start` in a production environment. It starts the development server, but you already have the Node server running that serves files for you. So instead you should run `build` to create the final files. You then have to make Express serve files from the build folder. It can be done like this:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));
```

In app.js or server.js or whatever you call the Express file with middleware setup.
You should test the building part locally first, before pushing to Heroku. Don't start the development server, try to serve the React files from the backend to see that it works.

Comment: Thank you! Very detailed and addresses the problem with the server that I've encountered after adding the extra npm install script. Unfortunately I'm still having trouble getting the pages to show and am receiving a "Cannot GET" message.